# Unable to get Values from Enumeration using Automapper in ASP.NET Core C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, automapper

I am using PosgreSQL to return data into my Web API.

I have created my DTO class like below:

```
    public class SuppressionItem
    {
            public long AccountId { get; set; }
            public Account Account { get; set; }
            public CommunicationChannel Channel { get; set; }
            public NotificationLogStatus Status { get; set; }
            public string RecipientId { get; set; }
            public string ContactId { get; set; }
            public string Reason { get; set; }
            public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    }
```

In the above DTO class `CommunicationChannel`, and `NotificationLogStatus` represents an `enum`, which are shown like below:

```
public enum CommunicationChannel
{
    Email = 0,
    Sms = 1,
    WhatsApp = 2,
    [Description("Push Notification")]
    Push = 3,
    // Some more values were removed for brevity
}

public enum NotificationLogStatus
{
    Created = 0,
    Processing = 1,
    Sent = 2,
    Failed = 3,
    Delivered = 4,
    Undelivered = 5,
    // Some more values were removed for brevity
}
```

My `DndContact` class has been defined like below. This class also contains two methods to return appropriate strings for its integer equivalents based on switch case statement.

```
[PrimaryKey(nameof(AccountId), nameof(Channel), nameof(RecipientId), nameof(ContactId), nameof(Status))]
public class DndContact
{
    public long AccountId { get; set; }
    public Account Account { get; set; }
    public CommunicationChannel Channel { get; set; }
    public NotificationLogStatus Status { get; set; }
    public string RecipientId { get; set; }
    public string ContactId { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public string GetChannelName()
    {
        switch (Channel)
        {
            case CommunicationChannel.Email:
                return "Email";
            case CommunicationChannel.Sms:
                return "Sms";
            case CommunicationChannel.WhatsApp:
                return "WhatsApp";
            case CommunicationChannel.Push:
                return "Push";
        // Some more entries were removed for brevity
            default:
                return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public string GetStatusString()
    {
        switch (Status)
        {
            case NotificationLogStatus.Created:
                return "Created";
            case NotificationLogStatus.Processing:
                return "Processing";
            case NotificationLogStatus.Sent:
                return "Sent";
            case NotificationLogStatus.Failed:
                return "Failed";
            case NotificationLogStatus.Delivered:
                return "Delivered";
        // Some more entries were removed for brevity
           default:
                return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Written the below code to cast `DndContact` data to `SuppressionItem` data.

```cs
        public async Task<IEnumerable<SuppressionItem>> GetSuppressedItemsAsync()
        {
            var dndContacts = await _db.DndContacts
                                    .Where(x => x.Status == NotificationLogStatus.Suppressed)
                                    .ToListAsync();
            var suppressionList = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SuppressionItem>>(dndContacts);
            return suppressionList;
        }
```

But, I am unable to get the casted values for `Contact`, and `Status` fields as per the switch statement written in my `DndContact` class. I am not sure where went wrong.

Searched in Google, but I didn't get any result which can help me to resolve my issue.

Can someone suggest me if I am doing wrong, or if I am missing something?

Regards,
Ashok Kumar K.

Comment: First try to remove the switch/case. A simple `.ToString()` should do that job. Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ynoZBS

Comment: Also: post the relevant MapperConfiguration.

Comment: I guess your name-getting methods must have some problem, that's not obvious. This works : https://dotnetfiddle.net/64qupX

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Fix is simple, but unfortunately, I got idea only after I submitted the doubt is Stackoverflow.

Modified `SuppressionItem` class like below to introduce two new properties - `ChannelName`, and `StatusString`

```
    public class SuppressionItem
    {
        public long AccountId { get; set; }
        public Account Account { get; set; }
        public CommunicationChannel Channel { get; set; }
        public NotificationLogStatus Status { get; set; }
        public string ChannelName { get; set; }
        public string StatusString { get; set; }
        public string RecipientId { get; set; }
        public string ContactId { get; set; }
        public string Reason { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    }
```

Modified `CreateMap()` method in `MappingProfile` class like below to use the newly created properties:

```
        CreateMap<DndContact, SuppressionItem>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ChannelName, options => options.MapFrom(src => src.GetChannelName()))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.StatusString, options => options.MapFrom(src => src.GetStatusString()));
```

Comment: The `MapFrom`s are not needed. The `Get` prefix is used by default in AM. See https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#recognizing-pre-postfixes

Comment: None of that is relevant. Check the example Fildor provided with working code. This is a low quality answer to a low quality question. You're supposed to provide working code, not make people guess what the actual problem is. You're obviously missing smth.

Answer (score -4):

It appears that the problem is due to how AutoMapper handles enum mappings. When mapping enums, AutoMapper may not use your GetChannelName and GetStatusString functions. Instead, it could be attempting to directly translate the enum values.

To address this, you can use AutoMapper's ConvertUsing method to define how your enums should be converted. Here's how to add the enum mappings to your AutoMapper configuration:

```
 public class MappingProfile : Profile
 {
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<DndContact, SuppressionItem>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Channel, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetChannelName()))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Status, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetStatusString()));

    // Add other mappings as needed
}
```

}

ForMember is used in this configuration to specify specific mappings for the Channel and Status properties. The values for these properties are provided by the GetChannelName and GetStatusString methods.

Check that the AutoMapper profile is configured in your application and that it is being used during mapping.

Check that the GetChannelName and GetStatusString methods in your DndContact class are functioning properly. If you're still having problems, consider adding some logging or debugging statements to observe what values these methods are returning during the mapping process.

Comment: That's really not necessary: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qLvX7W Both `DndContact` as well as `SuppressionItem` have the exact same properties with both the enum types.